# Multisite/network--automatic self-registration, blog setup

Tags: multisite, automation

I am creating a WordPress Network multisite blog in a university environment. It's set up in subdirectory mode, so that each new blog appears as a subdirectory off a common domain name.

The Network authenticates against our corporate Active Directory using LDAP. Only Active Directory users may sign in.

The first time a user signs in, our Active Directory plugin creates a WordPress account that corresponds to that user's Active Directory account. Each subsequent sign in, that account's properties are updated with the Active Directory account information.

We expect to have hundreds, possibly thousands of blogs in the system. In the interest of reducing administrator time, I want this to be automated, either:

1. From time to time, we run a script that checks the WordPress network against our Active Directory and automatically creates or deletes blogs depending on whether the blog's name corresponds to an account in the Active Directory.
2. Users may self-register for their own blog, and the blog's URL is based off an attribute of their account that will be imported from the Active Directory.

So far, my searches are not revealing canned ways of doing this.

Are there existing modules that can help? Or am I looking at something custom?

Comment: This sounds very custom - have you looked at the tools in wp-cli to automate the wordpress side of this?

Comment: We're mostly a .NET shop, so we're going to make a separate .NET-based app that does all of this and talks directly to the WordPress database.

Comment: Whilst unfamiliar with LDAP and Active Directory if it's simply a case of updating user information each time you log in - use `update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);` in the login loop, assuming you can pass data through the variables?

Comment: I'd definitely explore the use of wp-cli especially for creation/deleting sites. My advice would also be not to directly change the database unless the changes you make are to entries outside of the WordPress core (i.e. plugin specific).

Failing that you can set up a cron job

Your final option (apologies if this is against the rules) would be to look at some premium plugins like the ones here: https://premium.wpmudev.org/projects/tag/wordpress-multisite/#plugins-filter

Comment: Is this still an open question, or did you find/develop a solution you can share?

Comment: We're hacking together a C# application that will do that directly against the database.

Comment: How did you go with this @ArenCambre? Do you mind sharing your solution?

Comment: On #2 above, I hacked the script that permits people to create sites so that it forces them to only use an attribute of their active directory account. We still do not have a solution yet for #1.

Answer (score 0):

Use Active Directory Integration plugin and any membership plugin for managing membership registration and management. Check s2membership, paidmembershippro.

Use pro-site plugins (and other) from WPMUdev for multi-site auto-provisioning. 
Or if you already use WHMCS, you could get WHMCS multisite auto-provisioning module.